# How to get all viewmodel fields which is used in ASP.NET Razor view template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to get all viewmodel fields which is used in razor view template.
Template:

```
@model App.Models.Person
Name: @Model.Name
Age: @Model.Age
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Age { get; set; }
  public string Role { get; set; }
  public string Departament { get; set; }
}
```

And result of my needs is array of two strings:

```
['Name','Age']
```

Purpose of our needs is check this fields in csv file, which we import to database, before client import them. View templates are designed by client and we dont know which fields they will use.

Is any way to get this by ViewContext, or I must read all lines of template, and find @Model pattern and extract field which I want?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Why would you need this ?

Comment: For what purpose are you doing this? Are you just trying to find references to things so you can change them or does your actual application need to be able to access this information (and if so, why)?

Comment: I update my question by: "Is any way to get this by ViewContext, or I must read all lines of template, and find @Model pattern and extract field which I want?"

Comment: Purpose of my needs is only check this fields in file, which we import to database.

Comment: Still don't get it... on what stage do you perform this check? OnActionExecuting, OnResultExecuting, OnResultExecuted etc? In controller after model was posted?

Comment: Hmm, it's quite complicated. We want to check it before we import the csv file to database, not before we render the view. View templates can change our client, well we cant check our viewmodel by our repo and we dont know which field our client use in template. :-/

Comment: Reading all lines of template might not be enough - what about cases like LabelForModel(m => m.Name) or var foo = Model; foo.Name etc.

Comment: You're right. I want to avoid reading all lines.